# .net bootstrapper for online distribution

Tags: .net, bootstrapper

I know how to build a .NET bootstrapper to be distributed via CD/DVD using dotnetInstaller. But I am planning to distribute my application over internet. I have an .msi and dependencies like .NET framework 3.5, Crystal report and a couple of more. I want that when a user want to use the application, he clicks on download link...a single .exe is downloaded. Then when he starts installation, pre-requisites like .NET framework 3.5, Crystal Report and other prerequisites are downloaded from net and installed and finally my .msi is installed.

I went through the documentation of dotnetInstaller but unable to figure it out.

So guys anyone has got experience over it...please give me guide me out...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I got the solution for what I was looking and it is iExpress. It is always there in windows.

http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/how-to-make-an-exe-installation-file/

Answer (score 7):

You might want to have a [look at ClickOnce](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t71a733d%28v=VS.100%29.aspx)

Using ClickOnce you can distribute from a CD (or the web), include a bootstrap to install prerequisites  and keep the program up-to-date.

**EDIT**

If you want to install the application in Program Files you have to first install the application from a CD or share that is trusted and install the application as an administrator. [After that ClickOnce can be used to keep the application up-to-date](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s22azw1e.aspx).

Comment: No at present I am not looking for clickonce as it does not give the flexibility to create your own folder structure.

Comment: What folder structure are you referring to (you might be wrong)? And why didn't you put this requirement in the question?

Comment: @Erno +1 for Clickonce. Maybe Bikram thinks about that the installed application is installed to some arcane place to some internal folders and not to some well known location like Program Files

Comment: To clarify: ClickOne uses regular MSIs. So not all (im)possibilities come from ClickOnce.

Comment: Ya..gyurisc is right. What I suppose is that, clickonce application does not install an application in the regular Program Files folder structure. Also the data files are not stores in Program Data etc...I am not sure but this is what I came to know from googling. Erno, please correct me if I am wrong and provide me some good links from where I can get some reliable info...

Comment: As I commented before, ClickOnce can use a regular MSI. So anything that you can do using an MSI can be done by ClickOnce (provided you use a local setup, not a download/web setup) If program saves data in the wrong folder it is caused by the program NOT by ClickOnce.

Comment: Thnx..Erno..I hope it will be helpful.

Comment: Yes, ClickOnce is fine and I will dig it further for implementation. But for now, as per our requirement I prefer to go with dotNetInstaller. So looking for inputs from fellow developers/config managers...

Comment: Would you care to explain why dotNetInstaller?

Comment: simple because I am a novice in clickonce and may change to it any time if get its flavour.But has some previous experience with dotNetInstaller so a preference...no more reasons

Comment: As suggested by Erno I digged further on ClickOnce but still disappointed. As I rose the problem with clickonce for installer folders limitations, here is one such discussion http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/winformssetup/thread/84b5ed72-2406-4518-97e7-f7c6cf7132a7 . What I really want is as most downloadable applications give a download link. Clicking there you get an exe(normally but sometimes msi) downloaded. On its installation the application is installed with any prerequisites downloaded from net. I need the same structure.All my search on ClickOnce disappointed me on the same.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is called [Omaha](http://code.google.com/p/omaha/). This one is similar to ClickOnce, but used by Google to install and update their applications (Google Chrome, Google Earth) on Windows clients.

[Omaha Overview](http://omaha.googlecode.com/svn/wiki/OmahaOverview.html)